# convert String to type const char* using Arduino

Tags: c++, casting, arduino

I am using the Arduino library.  I would like to log some data from a sensor, date-time stamp it and write it to a SD card.

To build the text file name I have tried

```
    String dataFileName = String(String(sedClock.getTime().year(),DEC) + 
                         String(sedClock.getTime().month(),DEC) + 
                         String(sedClock.getTime().day(),DEC) + 
                         String(sedClock.getTime().hour(),DEC) + 
                         String(sedClock.getTime().minute(),DEC) + 
                         String(sedClock.getTime().second(),DEC) + '_log.txt');
```

I would then like to log to that file using

```
      pinMode(SD_PIN,OUTPUT);
      dataFile = SD.open(dataFileName,FILE_WRITE);
```

But I get

```
    no matching function call to SDClass::open(String&, int) 
    candidates are: File SDClass::open(const char*,uint_8)
```

But it seems that Arduino string doesn't have the equivalent of

```
    (const char *) dataFileName.c_str()
```

So I can't figure out how to do the correct conversion

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Thanks for your help.  The solution was

```
    char __dataFileName[sizeof(dataFileName)];
    dataFileName.toCharArray(__dataFileName, sizeof(__dataFileName));

    pinMode(SD_PIN,OUTPUT);
    dataFile = SD.open(__dataFileName,FILE_WRITE);
```

Comment: use str.length()+1 for get length String. For example:  char __dataFileName[dataFileName.length()+1];
    dataFileName.toCharArray(__dataFileName, sizeof(__dataFileName));

Answer (score 3):

How about [`StringToCharArray`](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference.StringToCharArray) or [`StringGetBytes`](http://arduino.cc/en/Reference/StringGetBytes)?